# EAccessViolation exception!!! (detailed, With images)

Tags: delphi, memory-management, memory-leaks

Well, here I am again, trying to resolve an old problem.

Briefly, I get an AV when I try to free a modal form which does not have any owner, and didnt have been freed before.

```
frmItensVenda := TfrmItensVenda.Create(nil);
                frmItensVenda.vtipo := vtipo;
                frmItensVenda.vcontrole := strtoint(edit1.Text);
                frmItensVenda.Ednota.Text := Edit5.Text;
                frmitensvenda.lbvend.Caption := combobox3.Text;
                frmitensvenda.lbnome.Caption := combobox1x.Text;
                frmItensVenda.limite := limite;
                if label10.caption <> '' then
                    frmItensVenda.vcli := strtoint(label10.caption);
                frmItensVenda.ShowModal;
                Frmitensvenda.Close;
                frmItensVenda.Free;
```

If I just activate it and then close(without doing a thing), no AV happens. Putting a break-point before the 'free' command, it shows me the variable inside the form if I put the mouse cursor on it.

But if I insert one item in the grid, using the breakpoint at the same place, when I move the cursor to the same line, it doesnt show the variables anymore, but says 'inacessible value'.

And if I proceed running the code, as the next line has the 'free' command I get an AV.
What makes me believe there is some piece of code on that procedure that is doing something unexpected to the code, but I can tell you that there is no 'free' or similar command to the form in question there.

My solution(temporary) was to just comment the '.free' command, but if I run MadException I got a memory leak when I close the application (hey, anything  is better than this EAccessViolation thing for me right now..)
Any sugestions?

Comment: I think you should cut the problem down to a minimal reproduction and post that code. Then we can help.

Comment: The other thing you should do is start using try and finally to protect against leaks. Ken's example code from your previous questions shows how to do that.

Comment: I was edditing the images, the idea was to show that in the first case, I could see the variables inside `frmitensvenda` and in the second case it was unacessible, but I guess you're right

Comment: That's expected. The problem is that something else, it seems, has a reference to the form. And we really need to know what else has the reference. That's what you need to look for. Is `frmItensVenda` a local variable?

Comment: `frmItensVenda` is a global variable automatic created(but not inicialized). The problem here, is that I took this source code with already 25+ thousand lines, I'm a beginer, and the code is poorly written(linear), and I'm really afraid to change the form variables names, because I dont know how far the changes can affect the rest of the code....

Comment: Is it possible the form's OnClose is sets Action to caFree?

Comment: Agree with David H. Back up (ie. copy) your form file(s) (.pas, .dfm) to a safe location, then aggressively chop out components and code until you you have a minimal reproduction set. You can start again with your backed up form files once you've isolated the problem. This process will have the added advantage of giving you confidence to re-write the "poorly written" code!

Comment: Is `frmitensvenda` set to auto-create? I've seen strange similar issues due to that.

Comment: Images of your code are totally useless. They're not only hard to read (especially from a mobile device), but the code can't be copied and pasted into an editor for testing. If you want to "go for what matters", **post your actual code, as properly formatted text**. Copy it from the IDE, paste it into your question, select it, and use Ctrl+K (or the `{}` button on the toolbar) to format it as code. Absolutely none of the iimages you posted were necessary or useful to the question you've asked here. You've left out "what matters" in favor of worthless images.

Comment: If you have so much code, changing drastically the way you are doing is going to cause problems. Your original AV is probably not caused by what you think. You need to track that down.

Comment: I also discussed the use of the IDE-generated global variables in my answer to your previous question, and explained why using them was a poor idea (with examples of the proper way to do what you're asking about here).

Comment: @KenWhite Going to edit the question as soon as possible, sorry for that, the idea didn't  work so well on practice.

Comment: @AlainD that's gonna be my next step, thanks

Comment: don't do a `frmitensvenda.Close;` after  `frmItensVenda.ShowModal;` it's closed if you close the form via `close button` or `modalResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, finally.
The problem was a global array.
It was declared
`vm1 : array[1..100] of currency;`
but it was assigned a value at position `0`.
To my despair, there was no error when the variable was assigned, just when I tried to free the form. 
So simple when you find it.. (!!!)
Well, at least I figured it out. Thanks everyone for the support!

Comment: When debugging, use range check on.

Answer (score 0):

> OP : frmItensVenda is a global variable automatic created(but not initialized).

I see you do `frmItensVenda := TfrmItensVenda.Create(nil);`

Look for `Application.CreateForm(TfrmItensVenda, frmItensVenda);` in your .dpr file.
If it is there you creating a new instance !

```
{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'AServer';
  ...
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmItensVenda, frmItensVenda);
  ...
  Application.Run;
end.
```

And yes, dynamic form management is a **must** really (expecially in large applications.).

At trouble with large `Forms`, part of my solution was to, as much as possible to create dynamic.
Only when they are needed and then free them straight after.

---

```
  frmItensVenda := TfrmItensVenda.Create(nil);
  frmItensVenda.ShowModal;
```

> OP : My solution(temporary) was to just comment the '.free' command,

don't do that : use instead

```
  frmItensVenda.Release;
```

The "Method Release" removes the form and frees its associated memory.

Release procedure;

description

With release, you can remove the form from memory.

Release is the form to be taken until after the execution of event handlers of the form and its child components is completed.

**In all event handlers release should be used instead free to avoid access violations.**

The cases where you need to use Release are times when you're in the middle of an event handler (eg, OnClick), where further processing after the event will have to access the form.

In that case calling Release instead posts a WM_RELEASE message which doesn't free the event until the event handler is done and control has returned to the message pump (ProcessMessages/Application.Run).

**Reading the delphi help though, it is recommended that you use the release command.**

As for the Release v.s Free method. My understanding is that "Release" is specific to forms, and allows form-related even-handlers to finish before freeing resources.

Whereas "Free" is a generic method of freeing an object from memory (so should also work with forms.)

Comment: interesting idea. I've read that release should be used in case you wanted to free a form by a command inside the form itself, but maybe it would be safer to use it all the time with forms...

Comment: @CristianTrein : Try it and did you get a `Inaccessible value`or not ?

Comment: Free is correct in the usage shown. Release is not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you explain why? I see where I couldnt use free, but  what's the downside about using release? thanks